# how read non-duplicate ipv4 addressess from a large file

Tags: java, algorithm, file

I have a big file with IPv4 addresses on each line.
I need to count non duplicate values from it, but file can be really large.
I tried to read each line and then put them in a hashset, but it is just horrible
so any ideas???

For example, `ipv4.text`:

```
12.333.333.3
12.2.22.2
...
..
..
..
..
etc
```

Comment: Idea: please add the necessary level of detail to your question. You *explaining* what your code does always carries the risk of you leaving out important details. So see if you can provide a [mcve]. There might be *many* things that give you bad performance that have *nothing* to do with your data structure. And well, if we really talk about SUPER LARGE files, then maybe you will need some sort of framework that allows you to distribute the work to more than one worker node.

Comment: Meaning: "it is horrible" is nothing we can help with. Because we neither know what you mean with that, nor can we look at your code to determine what exactly gives you bad performance for example. You know, it starts with stuff like: how are you processing the text? Do you do pattern matching, or just substrings, ... as said: details matter here. Try to reduce your code to the core elements, ensure it still is "horrible" then, and show that to us, and explain what "horrible" actually means to you. (and do that IN the question, not in comments please)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1531124/ghostcat.  horrible means a lot of consuming time

Comment: Can you read the addresses in and sort them into ascending order? Then, all your code need do is run through the list to remove the duplicates.

Comment: This question has been closed because the person that closed it thought it lacked clarity. The question is perfectly clear: count  the unique occurrences of IPV4 addresses in a file. Re-open the question, please.

Comment: @M.Gianota No, the question is not clear. See my comments. And note: it takes **three** votes to close a question. And note: if we assume the problem is "large memory footprint" ... sorting sounds like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a memory intensive task. Regular java collections or your own typical data structure implementations may not work. Basically, HashSet, LinkedHashMap, Trie implementation, etc. may not work. Based on your needs, [Bloom Filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) may or may not work.

Go for high performance collections in Java. Popular examples are [Trove](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/html/overview.html), [Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava), [PCJ](http://pcj.sourceforge.net/), etc.

Answer (score 0):

read all the IP addresses as strings into a list, then sort the list then all your program has to do is loop through the list and check if the current IP string is the same as the last one, if it is skip it otherwise add it to a list of unique IPs.

Comment: Wrong on so many levels. If there are so many lines that using a HashSet gives you trouble, rest assured: using a list, and sort, and iterate that probably many times will make everything "more horrible".